# How to repeat json object data in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have json objct like below:

```
{
  "url": null,
  "status": 200,
  "data": {
    "ROLE": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      }
    ],
    "CUSTOMERS": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      }
    ],
    "PRODUCT": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "permissionName": "AVAILABLE"
      }
    ],
    "PRODUCT_CATEGORY": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      }
    ],
    "PACKAGES": [
      {
        "id": 19,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      }
    ],
    "SZ_CONNECT": [
      {
        "id": 35,
        "permissionName": "SZ_CONNECT"
      }
    ],
    "USER": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "permissionName": "ASSIGN_ROLES"
      }
    ],
    "TERRESTRIAL": [
      {
        "id": 31,
        "permissionName": "ADD"
      },
      {
        "id": 32,
        "permissionName": "EDIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 33,
        "permissionName": "LIST"
      },
      {
        "id": 34,
        "permissionName": "DELETE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "All Permissions",
  "objectErrors": [],
  "errorCount": 0
}
```

I have to manipulate this in below format:

```
<label class="text-semibold">Role</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="control-primary" checked="checked">
                Add
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="control-primary" checked="checked">
                Edit
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="control-primary" checked="checked">
                Delete
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="control-primary" checked="checked">
                List
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And same format in rest of all category as: customer, product, packagings etc.

My componends class is as:

```
export class RolesComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: any;
  rolesForm: FormGroup;
  id: number;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private rolesService: RolesService) {
    this.rolesForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      permissionName: ['']
    })
    this.getRolesList();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  getRolesList() {
    this.rolesService.getRolesList().subscribe(result => {
        console.log("DataResult");
        console.log(result)
        this.items = result;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

I want to get this by json object.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? What are you trying to achieve? You want to display a JSON object inside a form? Or you want to retrieve the form values as a JSON object?...

Comment: I want to display JSON Object in Form

Comment: OK, I've added an answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values for the fields need to be set by the FormBuilder, NOT in the template.

For example:

```js
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private rolesService: RolesService) {
  // Let's assume you can access your JSON data from here.
  const jsonData = { ... };

  // Use your JSON data to initialize the fields with default values.
  this.rolesForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [jsonData.id],
    permissionName: [jsonData.permissionName]
  });
}
```

Which type of data you pass to your fields depends on the types of the fields: some fields like `<input type="text">` only support strings, whereas other fields like `<select>` support arrays.

It could also be that you need to repeat the same field multiple times if you need to edit and collect multiple values. In that case, you need to use a `FormArray` in your form model. (You'll find tutorials if you google "angular formarray".)